# JOLT remove list levels in nested JSON

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I have JSON files where the elements are embeded in lists, with unnecesary sub-levels. I need to simplify this structure with JOLT but I can't figure out how. I looked at similar Q&As but I didn't find examples that would be similar enough.

Here is the input:

```
{
  "datasets": [{
    "datasetid": "id_of_1st_dataset",
    "metas": {
      "domain": "mydomain",
      "records_count": 120234,
      "keywords": ["foo", "bar"]
    },
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "1st_field_of_1st_dataset",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "2nd_field_of_1st_dataset",
        "type": "int"
      }
    ]
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "id_of_2nd_dataset",
      "metas": {
        "domain": "mydomain",
        "records_count": 5402,
        "keywords": ["banana", "bar"]
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "1st_field_of_2nd_dataset",
          "type": "text"
        },
        {
          "name": "2nd_field_of_2nd_dataset",
          "type": "int"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the desired output:

```
{
    "datasetid": "id_of_1st_dataset",
    "domain": "mydomain",
    "records_count": 120234,
    "keywords": ["foo", "bar"]
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "1st_field_of_1st_dataset",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "2nd_field_of_1st_dataset",
        "type": "int"
      }
    ]
    },
 {
      "datasetid": "id_of_2nd_dataset",
        "domain": "mydomain",
        "records_count": 5402,
        "keywords": ["banana", "bar"]
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "1st_field_of_2nd_dataset",
          "type": "text"
        },
        {
          "name": "2nd_field_of_2nd_dataset",
          "type": "int"
        }
      ]
    }
```

What would be the right jolt SPEC to transform this input into this output? Thanks in advance for your attention and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with the below spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "datasets": {
        "*": {
          "datasetid": "[&1].datasetid",
          "fields": "[&1].fields",
          "metas": {
            "*": {
              "@": "[&3].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you very much!